# How do I validate a phone number (Not US) with a efficient way?

Tags: c

so I am doing my assignment and it requires me to do validate the phone number.

This is the phone number's format. 
[image: Example phone number: 012-7418521]

`XXX-XXXXXXX`. Where the X must be digits and the format must include a '**-**' "**Dash**"  on the 4th character and the total maximum characters is 11 including the "**Dash**".

*Edit: I forgot 1 more thing, the first digit of the phone number or format must be a '0' zero digit where I forgot to validate it in my code.*

My question is, is there any other efficient, simple and short way of validating the phone number format like using a loop or other methods that could be helpful.

This is my current way of validating at the moment. As I can't figure it out how to use a for loop to do it.

Question: Is my way considered efficient? I do not think so. By the way, I am using a function to validate it where I pass the array to the function and once it validates successfully it returns 1 otherwise 0.

Note: I am new to the coding world by the way.

```
int validateContact(char contact[]) {

    if (contact[3] == '-' && strlen(contact) == 11 && isdigit(contact[0]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[1]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[2]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[4]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[5]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[6]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[7]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[8]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[9]) > 0 && isdigit(contact[10]) > 0)
        return 1;

    else {
        printf("Error Phone!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `> 0` in all your `isdigit` calls?

Comment: @melpomene well " isdigit " returns a non-zero value if it is a digit otherwise it returns zero.

Comment: `-42` is a non-zero value. Why do you have `> 0` in all your `isdigit` calls?

Comment: Using a loop might be less typing, but the code would have to check every digit anyway so the runtime would be about the same.

Comment: @melpomene well when I tried printing the returned value out it shows 1. I never thought of it returning a negative value.

Comment: This could probably be done with `sscanf`.

Comment: @melpomene I forgot to add in , the first digit of the format must be '0'. How do I validate that with scanf? Sorry I am still very new to C.

Comment: @BoPersson Well do you have any good and efficient way to validate it?

Comment: Define _efficient_. If your criteria is cognitive complexity of understanding what the code does, the most effecient way would be to use regular expressions. You can use PCRE for that.

Comment: @Cash- I'm thinking of something like `int n = 0; sscanf(contact, "0%*2[0-9]-%*7[0-9]%n", &n); return n == 11 && contact[n] == '\0';`.

Comment: @myaut PCRE? I have never heard of that function. Could kindly show me how?

Comment: Using `sscanf()` would be tricky at best. Its propensity for skipping blanks makes it a non-trivial proposition.  You’d need to use scan sets and the `%n` conversion specifier, twice each, I think. Not a pleasant task for a novice.

Comment: PCRE is an abbreviation of Perl-Compatible Regular Expression, and is a library (or set of libraries) found at http://pcre.org.  It could undoubtedly be used to do the validation task, just as a steamroller can be used to crack walnuts.

Comment: "the total maximum characters is 11 "  Please provide a valid example where the length is less than 11.

Comment: This is fine for a school assignment, but for a lot of real situations, it isn't good enough. Pretty much the only *foolproof* way to validate a phone number is to call it with a validation code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code contains a function called `validateContact()`. It uses regex comparisons to achieve the check of the phone number the way you have asked. Hope this can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <regex.h>

bool validateContact(const char *contact) {
    regex_t preg;
    regcomp(&preg, "0[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{7}", REG_EXTENDED);
    if (regexec(&preg, contact, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    printf("010-1234567 match: %d\n", validateContact("010-1234567"));
    printf("110-1234567 match: %d\n", validateContact("110-1234567"));
    printf("010_1234567 match: %d\n", validateContact("010_1234567"));
}
```